# iOS database - implementation and data entry

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, sqlite

I'm brand new to Swift/programming in general. I want to make a drug reference app for iOS specific to my field (anaesthesia) as a hobby project which could potentially be useful.

Each drug will have a multitude of properties by which they can be grouped (eg chemical structure, receptor acted upon) or which can be searched (eg all opioids which do not contain preservatives).

It would look something like this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/drugs-medications/id337974028?mt=8

I think it would make most sense to use a read-only relational database, which would take data from an external source (eg XML).

My questions are:

What should I be reading about to implement this in Swift? SQLite? Core Data? Simplicity trumps performance I think.

How can data entry be made easier? I'd be most familiar with exporting XML from Access, but I'm sure (much) better options exist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably buy and read an entire book on iOS programming that cover database and SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I be reading about to implement this in Swift?

- [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/): documentation about Swift
- [iOS resources](https://developer.apple.com/ios/resources/): documentation about iOS
- [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html?utm_source=iosstash.io): documentation for the Apple-blessed database
- [GRDB.swift](http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift): documentation for an SQLite application toolkit
- https://www.raywenderlich.com: a website full of tutorials.

> Simplicity trumps performance I think. [...] How can data entry be made easier?

Make your app first: it looks useful. Make it better only then: the users of your app don't really care how it is implemented.